# How do I search artifacts from Artifactory within Jenkins scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I see $class: 'ArtifactoryChoiceListProvider' in pipeline input step but I could not get it working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a shared lib, though you could keep this in the Jenkinsfile if you needed to.

```
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher   

List artifactoryArtifactSearchList(String repoKey, String artifact_name, String artifact_archive, String branchName) {
    // URL components
    String baseUrl = "https://org.jfrog.io/org/api/search/artifact"
    String url = baseUrl + "?name=${artifact_name}&repos=${repoKey}"

    Object responseJson = getRequest(url)

    String regexPattern = "(.+)${artifact_name}-(\\d+).(\\d+).(\\d+).${artifact_archive}\$"

    Pattern regex = ~ regexPattern
    List<String> outlist = responseJson.results.findAll({ it['uri'].matches(regex) })
    List<String> artifactlist=[]

    for (i in outlist) {
        artifactlist.add(i['uri'].tokenize('/')[-1])
    }

    return artifactlist.reverse()
}

// Artifactory Get Request - Consume in other methods
Object getRequest(url_string){

    URL url = url_string.toURL()

    // Open connection
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection()

    connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuthString())

    // Open input stream
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()
    @NonCPS
    json_data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(inputStream.text)
    // Close the stream
    inputStream.close()

    return json_data
}

// Artifactory authentication
Object basicAuthString() {
    // Retrieve password
    String username = "artifactoryMachineUsername"
    String credid = "artifactoryApiKey"
    @NonCPS
    credentials_store = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList(
        'com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider'
        )
    credentials_store[0].credentials.each { it ->
        if (it instanceof org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.StringCredentials) {
            if (it.getId() == credid) {
                apiKey = it.getSecret()
            }
        }
    }
    // Create authorization header format using Base64 encoding
    String userpass = username + ":" + apiKey;
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());

    return basicAuth

}
```